# refactoring multiple pointers function in javascript

Tags: javascript, refactoring, conditional-operator

Hello I was wondering if somebody could tell me if its possible for me to replace the conditional if statements in the body of my while loop with a ternary operator. It is not a necessity I just want to know if it's possible

I have a simple multiple pointer function where if the two points in an array add up to 0 then it will print those two points. How would I change the while loop logic to use a ternary.

Function without ternary

```
function sumZero(arr) { 

    let left = 0;

    let right = arr.length - 1;
    
    while (left < right) {
        let sum = arr[left] + arr[right];
        if (sum === 0) {
            return [arr[left], arr[right]];
        } else if (sum > 0) {
            right--;
        } else {
            left++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't put a `return` statement in a ternary, it can only contain expressions.

Comment: A ternary is generally only useful if both branches of the `if` do the same thing with the result of their expression, e.g. assigning them to the same variable or returning them. You're not doing anything like that in your code.

Comment: thats something I considered I just needed a confirmation thank you I appreciate your help

Comment: **Syntax**  
`condition ? expr1 : expr2`  
**Parameters**  
condition (or conditions)
An expression that evaluates to true or false.  
**expr1, expr2**  
Expressions with values of any type.

As @Barmar said, we cannot put return statement in ternary.